# Перегрузить оператор + в обе стороны

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Как перегрузить оператор + так, чтобы можно было складывать мой класс с другим типом в обе стороны?

Т.е. чтобы можно было сделать `Myclass{} + 42` и `42 + Myclass{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
MyClass & operator += (MyClass &a, int b)
{
  a.value += b;
  return a;
}

MyClass operator + (MyClass a, int b)
{
  return a += b;
}

MyClass operator + (int b, MyClass a)
{
  return a += b;
}
```

> То есть надо 2 раза определять, хоть тело одно?

Да, надо два оператора. Но в приницпе можно сделать второй таким:

```
MyClass operator + (int b, const MyClass &a)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: То есть надо 2 раза определять, хоть тело одно?

Comment: @tbbt, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Это если `a+b` то же семантически, что и `b+a`. Вот попробуй так строки складывать... :)

Comment: @Harry, ну да, есть такое. Но в большинстве случаев это так. У меня и первый так же реализован - через `+=`.

Comment: А почему вдруг во второй перегрузке делается передача `int` по ссылке???

Comment: @AnT, опечатка, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Например, если у вас `MyClass` имеет конструктор от `int` - просто определить как свободный (вне класса) оператор

```
... operator+(const MyClass&,const MyClass&);
```

Тогда при суммировании просто выполнится неявное преобразование `int` в `MyClass`.

Можно - определить два оператора

```
... operator+(const MyClass&, int);

... operator+(int,const MyClass&);
```

Первый из них можно определить и как член, и как свободный; второй - только как свободный оператор.

P.S. Как правило, стоит определять сразу же и оператор `+=`, причем один вполне может определяться через другой...

Comment: То есть надо 2 раза определять, хоть тело одно, если не приводится к типу?

Comment: Да. Вас же не удивляет, что нужно определять, например, две функции - `void f(const MyClass&, int)` и `void f(int, const MyClass&)` - потому что это разные функции?

Answer (score 1):

1. Прямой ответ: написать отдельные перегруженные операторы для всех возможных комбинаций операндов `MyClass + int` и `int + MyClass`.
2. Однако, если семантика вашего класса такова, что он натуральным образом поддерживает сложение `MyClass + MyClass` и также неявное преобразование `int -> MyClass` (то есть не-explicit конструктор преобразования из типа `int`), то оператор `MyClass + MyClass` уже сам по себе будет "покрывать" и сложения `MyClass + int` и `int + MyClass` тоже:

   ```
   struct MyClass 
   {
     MyClass() = default;
     MyClass(int) {}

     friend MyClass operator +(const MyClass &, const MyClass &)
       { return MyClass(); }
   };

   int main()
   {
     MyClass a;
     a + 123;
     123 + a;
   }
   ```

   Именно для "симметричности" поведения класса в таких контекстах и рекомендуется реализовывать оператор `+` отдельностоящей функцией, а не методом класса.